# jQuery Add/Del/

Tags: jquery, expand

I have created a expand/collapse datagrid using jQuery. The datagrid has the following functionality like Add/Clone/Del/Select All table rows.

I have implemented for Add. Can anyone give me some tips for del/clone/select all...?

Here is the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/3fwyf/5/

Comment: so you want to remove/copy the last row or a selected row ? how can a row be selected for these tasks ?

Comment: When i check 2 items on the grid and hit copy, the selected rows should be cloned and appended below the rows. Selected rows should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var lastRowCount = 5;

            $('tr.parent').css("cursor", "pointer").attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse").click(function () {
                $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
            });

            $('tr[class^=child-]').hide();

            //var orderTable = $("#example");

            $("#btnAdd").live('click', function (e) {
                //Take the text, and also the ddl value and insert as table row.
                var newRow = '<tr class="child-row123"><td class="brdr">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="brdr"></td><td class="brdr">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="brdr">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><input name="checkboxNNNN" type="checkbox" id="checkboxNNNN" class="SelectCheckBox" /></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
                $("#example tbody").append(newRow.replace(/NNNN/g, ++lastRowCount));
                //var $orderTable = $("#example");
            });

            $('#btnDelete').live('click', function (e) {
                $('.SelectCheckBox:visible:checked').parents('tr').remove();
            });

            $('#btnCopy').live('click', function (e) {
                $("#example tbody").append($('.SelectCheckBox:visible:checked').parents('tr').clone());
            });

            $('#btnSelectAll').live('click', function (e) {
                $("#example").find('.SelectCheckBox:visible').attr('checked', true);
            });

            $('#cbSelectUnselectAll').live('click', function () {
                $("#example").find('.SelectCheckBox:visible').attr('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.detail, table.detail td, table.detail th
        {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        table.detail tr.parent
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="detail" id="example"
        style="border: none;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="10%">
                    Customer Item
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;
                </th>
                <th width="12%" rowspan="2">
                    Variable Header Data Field
                </th>
                <th width="8%" rowspan="2">
                    PO Number
                </th>
                <th width="2%" rowspan="2">
                    &nbsp;
                </th>
                <th width="10%" rowspan="2">
                    Available Quantity
                </th>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">
                    Quantity to Order
                </th>
                <th width="10%" rowspan="2">
                    Variable Data Field
                </th>
                <th width="10%" rowspan="2">
                    Variable Data Field
                </th>
                <th width="10%" rowspan="2">
                    Variable Data Field
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Fulfillment type
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <select name="fulfillmenttype" id="fulfillmenttype">
                        <option selected="selected">In-Plant</option>
                        <option>Service Bureau</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="row123" class="parent" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to expand/collapse">
                <td>
                    Request type
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input name="checkbox4" type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" checked="checked" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    J94
                </td>
                <td>
                    123456
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    200
                </td>
                <td width="7%">
                    180
                </td>
                <td width="5%">
                    198
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="11111" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="child-row123" style="display: none;">
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td width="6%" class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td width="10%" class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="SelectCheckBox" id="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/magnify.gif" width="12" height="12" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    60
                </td>
                <td>
                    60
                </td>
                <td>
                    66
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" value="2222" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="child-row123" style="display: none;">
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/magnify.gif" width="12" height="12" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    60
                </td>
                <td>
                    60
                </td>
                <td>
                    66
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="textfield3" type="text" id="textfield3" value="3333" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="child-row123" style="display: none;">
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="brdr">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/magnify.gif" width="12" height="12" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    60
                </td>
                <td>
                    60
                </td>
                <td>
                    66
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="textfield4" type="text" id="textfield4" value="44444" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <label>
    </label>
    ​<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add row" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Remove Row" />
    <input type="button" id="btnCopy" value="Copy Row" />
    <!--<input type="button" id="btnSelectAll" value="Select All" />-->
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbSelectUnselectAll" />Select/Unselect All
</body>
</html>
```